# implement a controller advice global exception handler, intercept the runtime exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception

Given a rest controller class `FizzBuzzController.java`, there is a `GET` API endpoint to be modified, which can throw three types of runtime exceptions:

1. FizzException
2. BuzzException
3. FizzBuzzException

Below is the endpoint for the `GET` API endpoint with a single path parameter.

`GET /controller_advice/{code}`

Exceptions are to be thrown based on the value of the path param `{code}` passed to the rest API.

Here is a series of requests and their corresponding expected responses:

`GET /controller_advice/fizz`:

Response Code: 500

Response Body:

```json
{

"message": "Fizz Exception has been thrown",

"errorReason" : "Internal Server Error"

}
```

`GET /controller_advice/buzz`:

Response Code: 400

Response Body:

```json
{

"message": "Buzz Exception has been thrown",

"errorReason" : "Bad Request"

}
```

`GET /controller_advice/fizzbuzz`:

Response Code: 507

Response Body:

```json
{

"message": "FizzBuzz Exception has been thrown",

"errorReason" : "Insufficient Storage"

}
```

`GET /controller_advice/success`:

Response Code: 200

Response Body:

```json
{

"message": "Successfully completed fizzbuzz test",

"statusCode": "200"

}
```

Your task is to complete the given project so that it passes all the test cases when running the provided unit tests.

For that, you have to implement a controller advice global exception handler, intercept the runtime exceptions thrown from the GET API endpoint, and return a response entity wrapped in the `GlobalError.java` class.

The runtime exceptions and error response classes are already predefined in the project. You just need to complete the implementation `controller` GET API endpoint and the `controller advice` classes.

### Commands

- run:

```sh
mvn clean package; java -jar target/RestControllerAdvice-1.0.jar
```

- install:

```sh
mvn clean install
```

- test:

```sh
mvn clean test
```

**ChallengeApplication.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class ChallengeApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  SpringApplication.run(ChallengeApplication.class, args);

  }

}
```

**FizzBuzzController.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.controller;

import com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto.BuzzException;

import com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto.FizzBuzzException;

import com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto.FizzBuzzResponse;

import com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto.FizzException;

import com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.enums.FizzBuzzEnum;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class FizzBuzzController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/controller_advice/{code}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public ResponseEntity<FizzBuzzResponse> getFizzBuzzResponse(@PathVariable("code") String code)

throws FizzException, BuzzException, FizzBuzzException {

if (FizzBuzzEnum.FIZZ.getValue().equals(code)) {

//throw new FizzException

} else if (FizzBuzzEnum.BUZZ.getValue().equals(code)) {

//throw new BuzzException

} else if (FizzBuzzEnum.FIZZBUZZ.getValue().equals(code)) {

//throw new FizzBuzzException

}

//return FizzBuzzResponse

return null;

}

}
```

**BuzzException.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto;

public class BuzzException extends RuntimeException {

private final String message;

private final String errorReason;

public BuzzException(String message, String errorReason) {

this.message = message;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

public BuzzException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace, String message1, String errorReason) {

super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);

this.message = message1;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

@Override

public String getMessage() {

return message;

}

public String getErrorReason() {

return errorReason;

}

}
```

**FizzBuzzException.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto;

public class FizzBuzzException extends RuntimeException {

private final String message;

private final String errorReason;

public FizzBuzzException(String message, String errorReason) {

this.message = message;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

public FizzBuzzException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace, String message1, String errorReason) {

super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);

this.message = message1;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

@Override

public String getMessage() {

return message;

}

public String getErrorReason() {

return errorReason;

}

}
```

**FizzbuzzzResponse.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto;

public class FizzBuzzResponse {

private String message;

private int statusCode;

public FizzBuzzResponse(String message, int statusCode) {

this.message = message;

this.statusCode = statusCode;

}

public String getMessage() {

return message;

}

public void setMessage(String message) {

this.message = message;

}

public int getStatusCode() {

return statusCode;

}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {

this.statusCode = statusCode;

}

}
```

**FizzException.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto;

public class FizzException extends RuntimeException {

private final String message;

private final String errorReason;

public FizzException(String message, String errorReason) {

this.message = message;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

public FizzException(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace, String message1, String errorReason) {

super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);

this.message = message1;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

@Override

public String getMessage() {

return message;

}

public String getErrorReason() {

return errorReason;

}

}
```

**GlobalError.java**

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.dto;

public class GlobalError {

private String message;

private String errorReason;

public GlobalError() {

}

public GlobalError(String message, String errorReason) {

this.message = message;

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

public void setMessage(String message) {

this.message = message;

}

public void setErrorReason(String errorReason) {

this.errorReason = errorReason;

}

public String getMessage() {

return message;

}

public String getErrorReason() {

return errorReason;

}

}
```

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.enums;

public enum FizzBuzzEnum {

FIZZ("fizz"),

BUZZ("buzz"),

FIZZBUZZ("fizzbuzz");

private final String value;

private FizzBuzzEnum(String value) {

this.value = value;

}

public String getValue() {

return value;

}

public static FizzBuzzEnum getStatus(String value) {

switch (value) {

case "Fizz":

return FizzBuzzEnum.FIZZ;

case "Buzz":

return FizzBuzzEnum.BUZZ;

case "FizzBuzz":

return FizzBuzzEnum.FIZZBUZZ;

default:

return null;

}

}

}
```

```
package com.hackerrank.restcontrolleradvice.exception;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@RestControllerAdvice

public class FizzBuzzExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

//TODO:: implement handler methods for FizzException, BuzzException and FizzBuzzException

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you indent your code correctly it will be easier to read. Thank you.

Comment: Also, it looks like you pasted some assignment as it is, it doesn't say whay you have tried and what didn't work and you already have controller advice in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you dont know how to implement your `ResControllerAdvice` class.

Here is how you should do it:

```
@ExceptionHandler(FizzException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleFizzException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    ExceptionResponse eR = new ExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false), ex.getClass());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(eR, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

@ExceptionHandler(BuzzException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleBuzzException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    ExceptionResponse eR = new ExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false), ex.getClass());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(eR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

@ExceptionHandler(FizzBuzzException.class)
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleFizzBuzzException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    ExceptionResponse eR = new ExceptionResponse(ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false), ex.getClass());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(eR, HttpStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE);
}
```

I hope I could help you and my answer is what you looked up for.

Keep your great work up!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below implementation of your RestControllerAdvice class.

```
@ExceptionHandler(FizzException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public @ResponseBody GlobalError handleFizzException(final FizzException exception,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    GlobalError error = new GlobalError();
    error.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
    error.setErrorReason(exception.getErrorReason());
    return error;
}

@ExceptionHandler(BuzzException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody GlobalError handleBuzzException(final BuzzException exception,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    GlobalError error = new GlobalError();
    error.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
    error.setErrorReason(exception.getErrorReason());
    return error;
}

@ExceptionHandler(FizzBuzzException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)
public @ResponseBody GlobalError handleFizzBuzzException(final FizzBuzzException exception,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {

    GlobalError error = new GlobalError();
    error.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
    error.setErrorReason(exception.getErrorReason());
    return error;
}
```

I hope it will helpful to you.